# How to optimise the Symfony4 Doctrine Repository usage inside the controller

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4

I'm looking for a optimised usage of the Doctrine Repositories inside the Symfony 4 Controllers.

At the moment i've to build the code like this:

```
/** @var ArticleRepository $repository */
$repository = $this->getRepository(Article::class);
$articles = $repository->findBySearchterm($search_term);
```

To tell truth, i don't like this approach. If i have to use `$this->getRepository(Article::class)`, i've to tell PHPStorm through extra annotation, that the return of that method is of type `ArticleController`. Otherwise PHPStorm warns me, that the called method `->findBySearchterm($search_term);` is unknown.

I would like to optimise this and use the ArticleRepository directly, maybe like this: `ArticleRepository::findBySearchterm($search_term);`

Is there a chance to build something, to access the Repository directly without the overhead of fetching the repository? In my opinion it would also increase the readability of the code.

Answer (score 3):

You can inject the repository directly into the controller method like so:

```
public function index(ArticleRepository $repository)
{
    $articles = $repository->findBySearchterm($search_term);
    // The rest of the code
}
```

This is done by symfony [autowiring](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html)

Comment: Also it's better to inject via `__construct` otherwise you'll have to typehint `index`, `add`, `edit` and other CRUD actions.

Comment: Thats nice! Why isn't this mentioned in the Symfony4 documentation ([link](https://symfony.com/doc/4.2/doctrine.html#fetching-objects-from-the-database))? This approach looks better for me. But, to keep the arguments list short, i would prefer the static usage i suggested. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Actually it is documented [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#injecting-services-config-into-a-service) and [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html). It is a good practice to use dependency injection. The doctrine repositories are not static, so you can't use static methods.